# Efficiently calculating the total number of divisors of integers in a range

Tags: math, prime-factoring

Given the range [1, 2 Million], for each number in this range I need to generate 
and store the number of the divisors of each integer in an array.

So if x=p1^(a1)*p2^a2*p3^a3, where p1, p2, p3 are primes, 
the total number of divisors of x is given by (p1+1)*(p2+1)*(p3+1). I generated all 
the primes below 2000 and for each integer in the range, I did trial division
to get the power of each prime factor and then used the formula above to calculate
the number of divisors and stored in an array.
But, doing this is quite slow and takes around 5 seconds to generate the number of divsors
for all the numbers in the given range.

Can we do this sum in some other efficient way, may be without factorizing each 
of the numbers?

Below is the code that I use now.

```
typedef unsigned long long ull;
void countDivisors(){
    ull PF_idx=0, PF=0, ans=1, N=0, power;
    for(ull i=2; i<MAX; ++i){
        if (i<SIEVE_SIZE and isPrime[i]) factors[i]=2;
        else{
        PF_idx=0;
        PF=primes[PF_idx];
        ans=1;
        N=i;
        while(N!=1 and (PF*PF<=N)){
            power = 0;
            while(N%PF==0){ N/=PF; ++power;}
            ans*=(power+1);
            PF = primes[++PF_idx];
        }
        if (N!=1) ans*=2;
        factors[i] = ans;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your formula is wrong.  According to your formula, the sum of the divisors of 12 should be 12.  In fact it is 28.  The correct formula is `(p1a1 - 1)*(p2a2 - 1) * ... * (pkak - 1)/( (p1 - 1) * (p2 - 1) * ... * (pk - 1) )`.

That said, the easiest approach is probably just to do a sieve.  One can get clever with offsets, but for simplicity just make an array of 2,000,001 integers, from 0 to 2 million.  Initialize it to 0s.  Then:

```
for (ull i = 1; i < MAX; ++i) {
    for (ull j = i; j < MAX; j += i) {
        factors[j] += i;
    }
}
```

This may feel inefficient, but it is not that bad.  The total work taken for the numbers up to `N` is `N + N/2 + N/3 + ... + N/N = O(N log(N))` which is orders of magnitude less than trial division.  And the operations are all addition and comparison, which are fast for integers.

If you want to proceed with your original idea and formula, you can make that more efficient by using a modified sieve of Eratosthenes to create an array from 1 to 2 million listing a prime factor of each number.  Building that array is fairly fast, and you can take any number and factorize it much, much more quickly than you could with trial division.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am sorry that I had asked the wrong question. I actually needed the number of divisors of each integer below 2 million.

Comment: @praveen Then just `factors[j]++;` instead of `factors[j] += i;`.